# Google Chrome not allowing camera access, even when trusted and on HTTPS site

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

My web app using webrtc to record video from the camera stoped working after the chrome v71 update, it seems camera permission is always denied, even when the site is https and i have manually allowed camera access.

Comment: does the camera show up in https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/

Comment: Yes it does, its weird

Comment: I have this same problem. https://webcamtests.com/ shows the camera but can't display it. Works fine in Slack, Safari, etc.

Comment: Ugh I have the same issue, does anyone have an update?

Comment: Updating here for anyone with the same issue: Our app defines a Feature-Policy HTTP header that whitelists "powerful" features that the site can use on each page in an attempt to increase security against hijacking.  The new page that used the camera wasn't in the whitelist.  This causes Chrome to respond with Permission Denied to camera requests without prompting or giving further info, no matter what the user settings are.  We needed to update the whitelist to allow the camera on that page.  Other browsers don't seem to implement this yet.

Comment: @AdamHamilton thank you for this comment, I was missing the same thing!